# Grassmanian of k-plane in R^n

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am reading the script  http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/geometrie/Lehre/WS16/DGII/script.pdf and I want to prove exercise 9 where you need to show that $G_1(\Bbb R^3) \subset sym(3)$ is a submanifold diffeomorphic to $ \Bbb RP^2 $.

The Grassmanian of k-plane in $ R^n $ is defined as follows

$ G_k(\Bbb R^n):= \{ p\in \Bbb R^{n \times n}|p^*=p , p^2=p, tr(p)=k \}$

and there is a theorem that says $ G_k(\Bbb R^n)$ is a submanifold of $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$ of dimension $k(n-k)$.

I don't really see how I can show it's a submanifold of $sym(3)$ and how it's diffeomorphic to $\Bbb RP^2$ .

Comment: According to your note, your $G_k(\mathbb R^n)$ is not defined as that.

Comment: What's your definition of $\mathbb R P^2$? I would say it is by definition $G_1 (\mathbb R^3).$

Comment: $ \Bbb RP^n$ should be all 1 dimensional line subspaces of $ \Bbb R^{n+1} $ or $ \Bbb R^{n+1}\ $\ {0} /~.

Comment: you are right, it is not defined as that .But in the script he stated  $G_k(\Bbb R^n)$ is equal to that above. My bad sry

Comment: Right, but how do you define the smooth structure? This question should amount to translating between whatever that description is and the description via orthogonal projections.

Comment: ah ok i know that {($ U_i, \phi_i$)} is a smooth atlas of $\Bbb RP^n$ (for i=1,..,n) with $U_i:=\pi$({$x \in X| x_i\neq0$}) and $\phi_i: U_i ->\Bbb R^n$ with [$x_1,...,x_n$]->$({x_1 \over x_i}$,...,$x̄_i$,...,$ x_n \over x_i$) where $\pi:X->\Bbb RP^n$ is the canonical projection x->[x] and $ X= \Bbb R^n $ \ {0}